# Numpy: apply function based on index and parameters

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a NxMx4 3D array, representing an image in RGBA, and a binary string, representing some text. I want to take vectors that have x,y coordinates that are both divisible by 2 (i.e. `[0,0],[0,2],...,[2,0],[2,2],...`) and then take the last element of each of those vectors and decrease it in 1 if the respective byte is a 1, or don't do anything if the respective byte is a 0.

As in, if the string is `"01100"`, with the first vector, don't do anything, decrease the second and third by 1, and then don't do anything for the rest. It's not really important if I have more vectors than elements in the string.

I have already managed to do it, using a sort of loop:

```
originalRows, originalColumns,_ = dataToEncrypt.shape



x,y = startx,starty
for char in binnaryMssg:
    if x >= originalColumns:
        x = startx
        y += Step
        if y >= originalRows:
                x = startx + 1
                y = starty + 1

    dataToEncrypt[y,x,-1] = dataToEncrypt[y,x,-1] - int(char)
    x += Step
```

Here, `startx`,`starty`,`Step` are all parameters of the function.

The thing is that this is a bit slow, around 0.38s for a text with 876 characters in an image with  918x575 pixels.

Is there a way to speed it up? I tried skipping the 0's using something like.

```
for char in binnaryMssg:
    if (char == "0"):
        x+= Step
        continue
```

But it just breaks everything, not letting me recover the original message.